# Error Registro WPF

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, visual-studio, wpf, registro

He creado una aplicación y tienes que registrarte para poder usarla. He creado el instalador y en mi ordenador funciona correctamente (las validaciones aparecen), pero en el resto de personas que la han probado, el registro de usuario funciona pero al darle al botón de registrar la aplicación rompe.

Uso UniserverZ con una base de datos, cosa que les digo como instalar y les paso todo lo necesario. Por si sirve, la aplicación está creada en Visual Studio 2019. El resto de la aplicación, que realiza updates e inserts en la aplicación los hace correctamente.

```
`con = new conexion(); //inicio conexion con base de datos externa
if (con.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into perfil (id_user, user, password, nombre, edad, sexo) 
    values (1,'" + user.Text + "', '" + password2.Password + "', '" + nombre.Text + "', " + edad + " , '" 
    + sexo + "')", con.Getconn());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Registro con éxito");
    con.CloseConnection();
}`
```

Todos los datos que aparecen están validados y comprobados de que son los datos correctos. La conexión es correcta porque si no esta pantalla no aparece.

Comment: Y que error da? Deberias hacer un log para poder grabar e investigar el error en las otras maquinas.

Comment: El problema que no puedo hacer un log porque es en el instalador, no paso el proyecto con la aplicación y se arranca desde Visual Studio. Bueno no se si se puede hacer en este caso o alguna manera para ver que ocurre, porque lo que hace la aplicación es romperse, es decir, como si le das al botón de salir.

Comment: Deberias hacer un log para guardar en un txt y colocarlo en el try catch de donde crees que rompe

Comment: Fácil, levanta una máquina virtual y lo corres ahí, coloca try-catchs en las partes importantes y que genere archivos de texto con el detalle de las excepciones.

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes generar logs con tryCatchs de esta forma y saber que pasa con tu aplicación:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UVHIcc67vE

https://hdeleon.net/como-crear-una-clase-para-logsbitacora-en-c/

**Yo lo implementé de esta manera:**

```
public class Logger
{
    private int processID;
    private string path = "";
    public Logger()
    {
        this.processID = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
        this.path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\IMT\\HIADDe\\Logs\\";
    }
    public void Add(string logEntry)
    {
        CreateDirectory();
        string name = GetNameFile();
        string logData = "";
        logData += DateTime.Now + ";" + "PID " + processID + ";" + logEntry + Environment.NewLine;
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(path + "/" + name, true);
        streamWriter.Write(logData);
        streamWriter.Close();

    }
    private string GetNameFile()
    {
        string name = "";
        name = "log_" + DateTime.Now.Year + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day + ".txt";
        return name;
    }
    private void CreateDirectory()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Lo uso en alguna clase así:**

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
logger.Add("Mensaje");
```

**O:**

```
Logger logger = new Logger();
try
{
    //Codigo que podria generar error
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Add(ex.Message);
}
```

**Y el archivo de texto generado tiene esta forma:**
[image: log.txt]